# neo4j - query latency issue with large relationship dataset

Tags: neo4j, cypher

Need help in reducing neo4j query latency issue with large relationship dataset.

**System configuration**
8 core, 32 GB VM on cloud

**Neo4J configuration**
page cache - 20 GB
heap - 8 GB

**ObjectModel**
Nodes share a relationship "COMMUNICATING_TO" with a relationship property "timestamp".

**Query**
find all the communications between nodes for a given time period, remove duplicate communications between two given nodes.

```
MATCH (n1)-[r:COMMUNICATING_TO]->(n2) 
WHERE r.timestamp >= <fromTimestamp> AND r.timestamp <= <toTimestamp>
RETURN {id:id(n1)} as fromNode, COLLECT(DISTINCT {id:id(n2)}) as toNode
```

**Data**
100K nodes, with 500 millions relationships between them.

**Challenge**
For a given day, there are **2 million relationships** that exist and the query time is **~50 seconds**.

Any suggestions that can help in optimizing the query, system parameters and the object model is appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `APOC` to create a manual index on your relationship.

This is the query to populate your index :

```
MATCH ()-[r:COMMUNICATING_TO]->()
CALL apoc.index.addRelationship(r,['timestamp'])
RETURN count(*)
```

An then you can retrieve your relationships like than :

```
CALL apoc.index.relationships('COMMUNICATING_TO','timestamp:[<fromTimestamp> TO <toTimestamp>]') YIELD rel, start , end
RETURN rel, start, end
```

Link to the doc : https://neo4j-contrib.github.io/neo4j-apoc-procedures/#_using_manual_index_on_relationship_properties

An other solution is to change your modelisation, by adding the date into  your `COMMUNICATING_TO`relationship type. Example : `20180205_COMMUNICATING_TO`, `20180206_COMMUNICATING_TO`, `20180207_COMMUNICATING_TO` ...

Comment: Thanks @logisima for valuable suggestions. Did look at adding manual index to the relationship. Faced issues in apoc, will re-try. On the second solution, there are options to model time series as nodes as in [Modeling Time Series Data with Neo4j] (https://www.graphgrid.com/modeling-time-series-data-with-neo4j/), but the query becomes complex to build.

Comment: You have to find the cursor between a more complexe modelisation, a more complexe query, and performances. Nothing is free ^^